# bootstrap-sass vs pure twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I know that Twitter Bootstrap may be customized while downloading it from Bootstrap website. How about bootstrap-sass gem - does it always include all the features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation, you'll see that you have the option of including all of the js, or only the scripts you want using `#= require` in your js/coffee files.

https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass#javascripts

Same applies to stylesheets, you can use `@import` to only include the files you want. You can look at the files architecture here:

https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets

The gem is actually an engine, it basically just adds assets, the same way the jquery-rails gem adds jquery and you can use it as if you had a jquery.js file in your `vendor/assets/javascripts` folder.